# Google maps refresh markers from database

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, arduino, maps

I search for few days but I didn't found a solution jet.
I'm currently working on a project where I need to receive information such as longitude and altitude from an Arduino save it on my DB and print it into another page using google maps.
I'm currently had problem refreshing the marker into the maps every 10 sec without refreshing all the page.
below I paste a copy of my code if someone can help me will be really appreciated

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png",
new google.maps.Size(32, 32), new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
new google.maps.Point(16, 32));
var center = null;
var map = null;
var currentPopup;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
function addMarker(lat, lng, info) {
    var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    bounds.extend(pt);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: pt,
        icon: icon,
        map: map
    });
}

function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
        zoom: 14,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR
        },
        navigationControl: true,
        navigationControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
        }
    });

<?php
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM valori");
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
      $lat=$row['latitude'];
      $lon=$row['longitude'];
     echo ("addMarker($lat, $lon);\n");
  }
?>

    center = bounds.getCenter();
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

</script>

<body onload="initMap()" style="margin:0px; border:0px; padding:0px;">
<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the map markers from DB without a page reload, you'll need to write an ajax call against a server endpoint/API that serves the updated (or new) geopoints.

I don't know your server setup, but on the client side assuming a JSON API, this could look something like:

```
function fetch_markers() {
    $.getJSON("/api/locations/latest", {}, function(res) {
        if (res.locations) add_new_markers(res.locations);
    }
}

function add_new_markers(locations) {
    locations.forEach(function(loc, i) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(loc.latitude, loc.longitude),
            title: "marker title"
        });
    });
}
```

Make sure you initialize your map variable globally so it's accessible in the methods above.

Your API will need to query your DB and return results in a format such as:

```
{"locations": [
    {"latitude": X, "longitude": Y},
    {"latitude": X, "longitude": Y},
]}
```

Finally you can set fetch_markers to be called every 10 seconds by setting an interval:

```
window.setInterval(fetch_markers, 10*1000);
```

Other things you'll need to consider is how to fetch the locations from DB. Such an app may need to store the last fetch timestamp and pass that to the server to make sure you're only fetching data points added since the last fetch. Specifics depend in your requirements of course.

Comment: thanks, Jeremy, I'm working now based on your suggestion! Thanks again for the useful help